# Juice UI Child Controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, controls, juice-ui

I'm trying to use container controls from the JuiceUI. So far I've played around with the [accordion](http://juiceui.com/controls/accordion) and [tabs](http://juiceui.com/controls/tabs). They're great controls, but I've having issues updating child controls within these control's "content" tags.

For the accordion, there's a PanelContent tag and for the tabs, there's a TabContent tag, but to make things simpler, we'll focus on the accordion.

Inside of the PanelContent, I have a label. I need to update this label with some info. Since I couldn't access the control directly, I tried casting the control from FindControl on the accordion itself. A NullReferenceException occurred. I also tried the same on the AccordionPanel and the same thing occurred. All of that makes sense.

On VBF, a member pointed out that the label was a child of the PanelContent. It doesn't have an ID property, so I couldn't directly access from the server side code. So I tried accessing it from the AccordionPanel. I could, but didn't have a FindControl method.

So with that, I'm not sure how to access that label from within that PanelContent tag.

Though, when I pull up the PanelContent property from the AccordionPanel, it has one method called InstantiateIn. It's intellisense description is below:

> Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As System.Web.UI.Control) When
>   implemented by a class, defines the System.Web.UI.Control object that
>   child controls and templates belong to. These child controls are in
>   turn defined within an inline template.

That *sounds* like what I need. But I'm not quite sure how to use it. The JuiceUI documentation doesn't seem complete, because I couldn't find anything on there about this.

Any ideas, guys?

Client Side:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table style="width: 99%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="CSO:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCSONumber" runat="server" CssClass="UpperCase" Width="115px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnRetrieve" runat="server" Height="22px" Text="Retrieve" Width="120px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="N/A" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <juice:Accordion ID="accSwrlHddRepl" runat="server">
            <juice:AccordionPanel runat="server" Title="HDD Information" ID="pnlHddInfo">
                <PanelContent>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOriginalHDD" runat="server" Text="N/A"></asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </PanelContent>
            </juice:AccordionPanel>
        </juice:Accordion>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there's a pending update to JuiceUI that hasn't been released which implements a 'FindControl' method for your scenario. The code is up on the source repository for it, but the nuget update hasn't been released.

You could try a fork named [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew) which already has that ability and is a close cousin to JuiceUI.